# Video Downloader no longer works

Tags: software-center

I installed the Video Downloader application via the Ubuntu software center and now it no longer works on YouTube (it displays "Missing Module: youtube_dl") and it has disappeared from the Software center in Gnome.  So I am unable to uninstall the app via the gui.  Is there a way to uninstall this app via terminal?  I could not find it when I did a list in apt-get.

Answer (score 0):

> "This afternoon, one of the most well-known pieces of software for
> downloading YouTube videos, youtube-dl, was removed from GitHub
> following a takedown notice from the Recording Industry Association of
> America, or RIAA.
>
> [...]
>
> This takedown notice does not necessarily spell the permanent end of
> youtube-dl. GitHub always immediately takes down any source code
> project that receives a DMCA notice like this, but the project’s
> creators will have an opportunity to file a counterclaim in the hopes
> of restoring youtube-dl’s status on GitHub. We’ll be keeping an eye on
> the situation as it develops.
>
> [...]
>
> In the meantime, those who still have youtube-dl on their device, or
> can obtain it from a mirror, are able to continue using it as normal.
> The larger issue is that youtube-dl will likely cease to receive
> updates for the time being, and therefore, any changes made by YouTube
> or other video services could potentially cause the tool to no longer
> function."

https://9to5google.com/2020/10/28/youtube-dl-github-riaa-takedown/

BTW. youtube-dl can still be downloaded manually from https://youtube-dl.org/

Searching the Web for "Video Downloader Ubuntu", I found the following page, which says that Video Downloader is a snap application (and it has been discontinued due to youtube-dl unavailability): https://snapcraft.io/install/video-downloader/ubuntu

So to uninstall it you should use: `sudo snap remove video-downloader`